# Common word to describe financial terms Trade, Position, Valuation, Collateral

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word to generically describe all of these financial terms: [trade](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/trade.asp), [position](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/position.asp), [valuation](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/v/valuation.asp?adtest=term_page_v14_v2), and [collateral](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/collateral.asp)?

**Example sentence**: "The Trade, Position, and Collateral classes all inherit from the abstract class _______."

There could theoretically be an additional category of items added to this set in the future. A broader term that is not too generic would be best.

The context is regulatory reporting of trades, positions, and collateral to governmental bodies, such as for the [EMIR regulation from ESMA](https://www.esma.europa.eu/page/post-trading).

Words like *asset* or *[security](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/security.asp)* may come to mind, however, a *position* isn't technically an asset because it is an abstract concept representing a positive or negative result of many trades--it is their net result, not the trades themselves. Plus, you can report both trades and positions for different underlying assets, or securities types, so those are really concepts at right angles to what I'm looking for.

A crude word might be *ReportableItem* but this is so generic as to be dissatisfying. I'd like to come up with a more specific term that describes these valid financial concepts—and that is also completely apart from the reporting context (it's for a layer of code that shouldn't know about reporting yet). *Item* is even worse.

*Collateral* can be securities such as [T-Bills](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/treasurybill.asp) but can also be cash. Cash is not really a security, either.

These terms are generically *TradeAspects* I suppose, and I think I'm getting closer with that, but this term is still unsatisfying as an *aspect* seems a far cry from an *item* or a real *thing*—it sounds like something less primary and more ancillary.

Later, in the reporting generation layer, I'm quite content to deal in *ReportableMessage* or otherwise a more generic term, but I need to separate the concerns for now.

While this word *is* for programming, I don't need programmer knowledge to get the best answer—I need English knowledge!

**Update**

The core concept here is that all of these are aspects of a business's dealings in derivatives that expose what's really going on to oversight. So I think the concepts of divulging, making visible, and exposing are heading in the right direction. Something like a *SecuritiesVisibilityFactor*. More promising words: *disclosure*.

**Bonus Question**

P.S. A *position* and a *valuation* are nearly indistinguishable, and in many cases are used interchangeably, and although they do have slightly distinct meanings in this business domain, for all intents they can be treated as the same thing. For bonus points, though, a new term that describes both of these would be quite useful as well. (I will accept for the first word, and vote up for the second word.)

**Example sentence**: "*The Trade, (1)_________, and Collateral classes all inherit from the abstract class (2)_________. A (1)_________ will later reported as a Position, a Valuation, or both (in two separate reporting messages).*"

<sup>*</sup>*Where (1) is this second word, and (2) is the word being requested above.*

**A Year Later**

The term that eventually won in the code and with which I am satisfied is `RegulatoryItem`. The other classes are `RegulatoryTrade`, `RegulatoryPosition`, `RegulatoryValuation`, `RegulatoryCollateral`, and so on. These are useful as they distinguish from versions of these classes that are specific to a particular regulator or data source.

Comment: "... all inherit from the abstract class FinancialTerm."

Comment: Downvoter: please help me improve my question, or help me understand why it is not a good fit on English Language & Usage. I'll happily improve it or delete it if you will only deign to enlighten me.

Comment: @HotLicks It's true that the **words** *trade*, *position*, and *collateral* are financial terms, but trades, positions, and collateral (themselves) aren't terms. They're... something else.

Comment: They're terms in equations.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm sorry that you don't understand me; perhaps you can sit this one out and spend your time on another question that will be more rewarding to you? By your logic, we should just say that "... all inherit from the abstract class Word." Since they're all words in a sentence.

Comment: Perhaps you should look up "term".

Comment: Dear @Hotlicks, I don't need to look up *term*. I'm not denying the words are terms. But the things they refer to aren't! The sentence "Hotlicks is a name and a human" is a good example for you. "Trade is a financial term and a business transaction" is the parallel. I'm looking for the second meaning, for a word that applies to the three concepts I listed. Can you understand the difference between the name of a thing and the thing itself?

Comment: You're asking for a term to cover some very disparate concepts: *events* (trade), *objects* (collateral), *states* (position) and *opinions* (valuation). I think you'll struggle to find an answer that *isn't* "dissatisfyingly generic".

Comment: So, look up the word "term".

Comment: @Hotlicks okay, I [looked it up](http://i.word.com/idictionary/term). Meaning 4a is the only one that seems relevant. And it says, "a word." Trades, positions, and collateral are not words--not in the sense I'm painstakingly explaining that I'm asking for. Just like Hotlicks is a name but also a human.

Comment: @JHCL if trades are events, then positions are summarized events—being promoted to objects is not obvious. And valuations are far from opinions, at least in the context of securities derivatives. It may be people's opinions that drive market forces, but an underlying security definitely has some form of objective price at a point in time, and such price is not an opinion (you'd pay close to that to buy it). In the context of reporting, positions and valuations contain nearly identical information. But you have a good point about their disparate nature. See my comment on the one answer so far.

Comment: OK, try "parameter".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're having trouble coming up with the proper name is that JHCL is right:  the name will have to cover "very disparate" financial characteristics of an exchange that are gathered only because of the happenstance that a regulatory agency wants to collect them.  You're close to realizing this when you mention the name *ReportableItem*.  Perhaps you might use a term related to the reason the regulators collect the data -- namely to characterize individual trades in the hopes that the collection will limn the entire market.  So something like *TradeCharacteristic* or *TradeDescriptor*.

I think your assumption that *position* and *valuation* are "nearly indistinguishable" may be misleading you.  Together they give you everything you need to know about *UnitInformation* in the trade.  *Position* is the number of units, and *valuation* and *position* together give you the worth per unit (by dividing the former by the latter).

Comment: The best name I've been able to think up since yesterday is *RiskExposingBusinessConcern* or "... Element" or something similar. For what it's worth, a regulatory position message has almost identical data to a valuation message: both contain the quantity and the mark-to-market value. Yes, in one sense a position is a scalar, but in another it is all the details of the security and the trading parties, too.

Comment: @ErikE It's interesting how difficult it is to categorize these terms.  I'm not fond of *RiskExposing* as most transactions aren't risky.  I believe the aggregate of the data might expose risk.  *BusinessConcern* collides with the meaning of "company involved in commerce."  The position is by definition a scalar, as its a simply a number with no direction.  Again the aggregate of the regulatory data will reveal *market* directions.

Comment: Right now I'm leaning toward *TradingAspect* after running a few names by a coworker. The term "Disclosure" was attractive to me, but it already has a lot of meaning bundled into it in this business space, so it's not suitable. *Position* here really means, "all the data surrounding a position"—I really don't intend the "single quantity" meaning of it. (And in fact, it has a direction because a futures contract holds either the short or long side, so the position value is respectively negative or positive.)

Comment: @ErikE Short or long, the value is still a scalar, i.e., just a magnitude.  Think of temperature, a scalar quantity, whether it's above zero or below.  A vector quantity must have both a magnitude and a direction.  Naming is often the hard part.  Your choices can make your life easier or harder, and they're hard to change once you start.  Good luck.

Comment: "Your choices can make your life easier or harder, and they're hard to change once you start." Yes!!! This is why naming matters so much to me. I know how deeply it informs later thought about the code.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually settled on *TradingAspect*, for now. The *Trading* prefix is better than *Trade* because that seems like it would apply only to trades. I might use a slight variation, perhaps a *TradingDatum* or similar, but this feels like the right direction.

Other possibilities:

- *TradingDescriptor*
- *TradingDescription*
- *TradingRecord*
- *TradingDetail*
- *TradingFactor*
- *TradingFactoid*